# Utility engineer trying to understand electric vehicle charging when the car is getting "topped off"

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging

I'm an engineer trying to understand the impact electric vehicles will have on service transformers and other customer facing grid equipment. I'm mainly interested in the energy consumption profiles of EVs, specifically how they charge as well as the nuances.

I understand that the vast majority of EVs charge using the constant current / constant voltage charging algorithm (CC/CV) or some variation of it, but I was wondering what happens when the vehicle is getting "topped off". For instance, if I fully charged my Tesla then drove 40 miles, what would the energy consumption profile look like when I plugged it back in? Would it jump back to its peak power rating (11.5 kW) immediately? Would it recognize that it is at a high SOC and trickle charge?

Couldn't find an answer in the literature. This is a big concern for us utility engineers as we want to quantify the impact of short commutes. Any insight anyone can share would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When I plug mine in, the display shows the charging power building up slowly, though whether that's the readout averaging or not I've no idea. I'd expect the vehicle to know what state the battery is in at all times.

Comment: CC/CV means that if the difference between the battery's nominal and actual voltage is small, it will be in CV mode, so it won't use full power if only little energy was used.

Comment: In addition, the "wall boxes" will avoid peak times and instead charge at some point during the night.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for how other EVs charge, but for my 2017 Tesla (90KW battery) the charge rate slows down the "fuller" the battery gets. For example, charging from 15% to 50% takes about 15 minutes, while charging from 90% to 100% takes half an hour.

Generally, you should avoid "topping off" an EV. It reduces the life of the battery. You should also avoid charging to 100%, partly because it wears the battery out faster and partly because the regenerative braking doesn't work above 90%.

By default, the car will stop charging at 90%. I only raise it if I'm going on a long trip.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, batteries charge relatively slowly, or quickly for only a short time, when near full charge.

At a given voltage (once reached from CC phase), the current drops over time.  Not quite exponentially (like a capacitor charging through a resistor), but slower (due to ionic diffusion, so current might drop more like \$t^{-1/2}\$ instead).

The exact response is complex, depending on charge/discharge history over a relatively long time scale (hours or days), but this is close enough for overview purposes.  The above also assumes a charging cycle with a step-like stimulus (which is to say: it'll respond differently if we modulate the current or voltage during charge, fairly obvious) -- but we also aren't too concerned about that, because other waveforms simply charge slower.

Anyway, you basically have the same gradually-decaying charging curve, and you start somewhere along it relative to SoC.  It can accept a lot of current from low SoC (limited by safe terminal voltage, internal resistance, and temp rise), which then tapers off over time (once reaching, then held at, CV).  At high SoC, you start quite far down the curve already, and not much current may flow; little or no CC phase might occur.  So, even if say 60 kW is available from the charger, only maybe 20 might flow, and tapering off over time at that.

The cutoff also depends; a charger could opt for a lower cutoff voltage (still waiting for the 10% or whatever termination current to occur, if not terminated by user sooner), or terminate it automatically (at higher than the usual threshold).  I don't know the specifics of premature cutoff; it may result in more wear, and certainly results in less charge (that's the point!), but that charge will eventually distribute itself through the cell (again, ionic diffusion going on) so it's not like you're missing out on efficiency or capacity (besides the capacity already lost to the early cutoff, which again, was the point, heh).

As for what the grid sees, at least for a single car, it's likely some kind of flat, then tapering off, load.  At least for single vehicles.  For multiple, the power supply may pass this to the grid as-is, or manage charge rates of multiple vehicles to give a smoother load -- for that, you'd have to ask the manufacturers if they have any strategies as far as managing loads.